# How can I join on multiple columns within the same table that contain the same type of info?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I am currently joining two tables based on `Claim_Number` and `Customer_Number`.

```
SELECT
A.*,
B.*,
FROM Company.dbo.Company_Master AS A
LEFT JOIN Company.dbp.Compound_Info AS B ON A.Claim_Number = B.Claim_Number AND A.Customer_Number = B.Customer_Number
WHERE A.Filled_YearMonth = '201312' AND A.Compound_Ind = 'Y'
```

This returns exactly the data I'm looking for. The problem is that I now need to join to another table to get information based on a `Product_ID`. This would be easy if there was only one Product_ID in the Compound_Info table for each record. However, there are 10. So basically I need to `SELECT` 10 additional columns for `Product_Name` based on each of those `Product_ID`'s that are being selected already. How can do that? This is what I was thinking in my head, but is not working right.

```
SELECT
A.*,
B.*, 
PD_Info_1.Product_Name,
PD_Info_2.Product_Name,
....etc {Up to 10 Product Names}
FROM Company.dbo.Company_Master AS A
LEFT JOIN Company.dbo.Compound_Info AS B ON A.Claim_Number = B.Claim_Number AND A.Customer_Number = B.Customer_Number
LEFT JOIN Company.dbo.Product_Info AS PD_Info_1 ON B.Product_ID_1 = PD_Info_1.Product_ID
LEFT JOIN Company.dbo.Product_Info AS PD_Info_2 ON B.Product_ID_2 = PD_Info_2.Product_ID
.... {Up to 10 LEFT JOIN's}
WHERE A.Filled_YearMonth = '201312' AND A.Compound_Ind = 'Y'
```

This query not only doesn't return the correct results, it also takes forever to run. My actual SQL is a lot longer and I've changed table names, etc but I hope that you can get the idea. If it matters, I will be creating a view based on this query.

Please advise on how to select multiple columns from the same table correctly and efficiently. Thanks!

Comment: How are the results incorrect?  Are you sure there is only one row for each product in `Product_Info`?

Comment: This is the issue. On some of the product ID's there are different product names, dependent on date. What I'm trying now is adding something like to the join:

    LEFT JOIN Company.dbo.Product_Info AS PD_Info1 ON B.Product_ID_1 = (SELECT TOP 1 Product_ID FROM Company.dbo.Product_Info WHERE B.Fill_Date >= PD_Info_1.Effective_Date DESC)

Anything to watch out for taking this approach? Thanks!

Comment: Then include the date in the join conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found put my extra stuff into CTE and add `ROW_NUMBER` to insure that I get only 1 row that I care about. it would look something like this. I only did for first 2 product info.

```
WITH    PD_Info
      AS ( SELECT Product_ID
               ,Product_Name
               ,Effective_Date
               ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Product_ID, Product_Name ORDER BY Effective_Date DESC ) AS RowNum
            FROM Company.dbo.Product_Info)
SELECT A.*
       ,B.*
       ,PD_Info_1.Product_Name
       ,PD_Info_2.Product_Name
    FROM Company.dbo.Company_Master AS A
    LEFT JOIN Company.dbo.Compound_Info AS B
        ON A.Claim_Number = B.Claim_Number
           AND A.Customer_Number = B.Customer_Number
    LEFT JOIN PD_Info AS PD_Info_1
        ON B.Product_ID_1 = PD_Info_1.Product_ID
           AND B.Fill_Date >= PD_Info_1.Effective_Date
           AND PD_Info_2.RowNum = 1
    LEFT JOIN PD_Info AS PD_Info_2
        ON B.Product_ID_2 = PD_Info_2.Product_ID
           AND B.Fill_Date >= PD_Info_2.Effective_Date
           AND PD_Info_2.RowNum = 1
```